# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor: How to get Action URL in a Javascript string variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@(Html.ActionLink("Link Label", 
    "ActionMethodName", 
    "ControllerName", 
    null, // parameter object, then html object
    null))
```

produces

```
<a href="/ControllerName/ActionMethodName/">Link Label</a>
```

If I want to reference the `/ControllerName/ActionMethodName/id` in a JavaScript template for the `Edit` or `New` link, how would I assign that to a JavaScript variable?

attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionUrl = '@(Html.ActionLink("","ActionMethodName",
                                       "ControllerName",null,null))';
</script>
```

but at that point, I would have to use Javascript to remove the unwanted `<a href...` characters in the string.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`@Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")` will generate a path.

Comment: What if there is a parameter/data object?

Answer (score 12):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")));
</script>
```

or if you already have this actionLink somewhere inside the page you could use it directly:

```
var actionUrl = $('#mylink').attr('href');
```

Just ensure to provide a unique id in order to simplify the selection:

```
@(Html.ActionLink(
    "Link Label", 
    "ActionMethodName", 
    "ControllerName", 
    null,
    new { id = "mylink" })
)
```